# Android - Notification Icons Very Small

Tags: android, onesignal

I'm using push notifications in my Android App. I'm using Android Asset Studio in order to generate my notification images.

However, the image is very small and I would like to fill the space of the notification area. Please se the below image:

[image]

You can find the notification images I'm using in my project [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1efMdgTgNbu06XGAjQZ5xNPxZvZiPoywf). 
(Generated by Android Asset Studio)

Code for showing notification [here](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/OneSignalSDK/onesignal/src/main/java/com/onesignal/GenerateNotification.java#L209).

Comment: Add your code for showing notification .

Comment: @ADM, I have updated my question.

Comment: I searched for a similar issue but it was icon in the notification bar and not inside the notification. I was using a drawable resource used in the app's launcher foreground instead of creating a new vector asset, which showed the icon about 50% smaller than other icons in the notification. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are only use `setSmallIcon()` . This icon will be displayed in status bar and as notification icon to if you do not set `setLargeIcon()`.

> Set the small icon resource, which will be used to represent the notification in the status bar. The platform template for the expanded view will draw this icon in the left, unless a large icon has also been specified, in which case the small icon will be moved to the right-hand side.

Set the LargeIcon. Use `NotificationCompat.Builder` instead example with `Notification.Builder`

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.app_logo);
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
     .setContentTitle("Title")
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
     .setLargeIcon(icon )
     .build();
```

Comment: That's right, I needed the Large Icon. Y added the following png /drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_onesignal_large_icon_default.png, as per OneSignal documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-icons

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could fix it by simply replacing the drawable with one without empty space around it. Also, here's the code I used:

```kotlin
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(appContext, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .build()
```

[image: Notification screenshot]